# Typescript/NodeJS window.onkeypress equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dom-events

Is there a way to achieve this:

```
 window.onkeypress = (event) => {
     // I want this to be called every time a key is pressed
 };
```

in node.js (TypeScript/JavaScript)?

Answer (score 0):

> in node.js (TypeScript/JavaScript)?

NodeJS doesn't have `window` so you cannot use `onkeypress`.

You can however read `stdin`: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin

Comment: I would like to register every character entered but not as a whole. I need to register each one of them with the timestamp they were entered... do you know if this is possible?